# @Published variable causes crash without didSet

Tags: swiftui

I have an `ObservableObject` view model with a `@Published` variable that's an enum indicating the status of the viewModel:

```
class BatchesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var lookupStatus: BatchLookupStatus = .none

    ...

}

enum BatchLookupStatus {
    case none
    case lookingUp(searchText: String)
    case error(errorMessage: String)
    case validated(batch: Batch)
}
```

I set the status when there's an error, or there's a validation, etc. I set the status back to .none when the error is dismissed.

Everything works fine, except I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash randomly.

I wanted to see what the status was when that happens, so I put a print statement when the status is set:

```
@Published private var lookupStatus: BatchLookupStatus = .none {
    didSet {
        print(_lookupStatus)
    }
}
```

I noticed that with that print statement, the crash no longer happens. In fact, if I just leave an empty `didSet`, it prevents the crash as well:

```
@Published private var lookupStatus: BatchLookupStatus = .none { didSet {} }
```

As soon as I remove the `didSet`, it crashes again.

What in the world is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the reason is not in the provided model, because as tested it all works as expected - I mean with Published-Refresh flow.

Here is an example of your model usage I did:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class BatchesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lookupStatus: BatchLookupStatus = .none
}

enum BatchLookupStatus {
    case none
    case lookingUp(searchText: String)
    case error(errorMessage: String)
}

struct TestPublishCrashed: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = BatchesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.lookupStatus = .error(errorMessage: "Search failed")
            }) {
                Text("Emulate Error").padding().background(Color.yellow)
            }.padding()

            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.lookupStatus = .lookingUp(searchText: "hello world")
            }) {
                Text("Emulate Query").padding().background(Color.yellow)
            }.padding()

            status.padding()
        }
    }

    var status: some View {
        switch viewModel.lookupStatus {
            case .none:
                return Text("No status")
            case .error(let error):
                return Text("Got error: \(error)")
            case .lookingUp(let query):
                return Text("Searching: \(query)")
        }
    }
}

struct TestPublishCrashed_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestPublishCrashed()
    }
}
```